# is there a way to register a factory in Unity's XML configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, unity-container

Is there a way to register a factory in Unity's XML configuration? 
Unity should inject some constructor parameters and use the factory in order to instantiate the object.

Here is a Spring .NET based example:

```html
<object id="name" type="Namespace.Factory, Assembly" factory-method="Create">
   <constructor-arg name="intParam" value="1" />
   <constructor-arg name="objParam" ref="objectName" />
</object>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to register a factory in Unity's XML configuration?

The short answer is no. On the Enterprise Library user voice there is a suggestion to [improve XML configuration](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/89245-enterprise-library-unity-vnext/suggestions/2612351-improve-xml-configuration) which include factory methods but it has not been implemented yet.

However, Stack Overflow user [Chris Tavares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422289/chris-tavares) has created a [Unity extension on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ctavares/unityfactoryconfig) with some support for factory methods in XML configuration.

To use this extension you would use XML configuration along these lines (where `FactoryCreated` is the type created by the factory):

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <sectionExtension type="Unity.FactoryConfig.FactoryConfigExtension, Unity.FactoryConfig"/>
  <alias alias="Factory" type="Namespace.Factory, Assembly"/>
  <container>
    <register type="NameSpace.FactoryCreated, Assembly">
      <factory type="Factory" method="Create"/>
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```

Unfortunately, this extension only support three types of static factory method signatures:

- `Create()`
- `Create(IUnityContainer container)`
- `Create(IUnityContainer container, Type type, String name)`

Your signature is different but based on this extension you could write your own implementing the rules you require.

Alternatively, it is very easy to specify a factory method using the fluent API at run-time but I guess that you are already aware of this.